# How to Find an ASP.NET Class Definition

Tags: asp.net, class, legacy

I'm working on a half-finished website created by another person who I cannot contact and I need to finish it.

There are some sections of code where a method from a custom object is called. I need to determine how these methods work and modify them.

How can I track down these class definitions for this site?

- I have ftp access to the site, but I can't seem to connect through Visual Studio 2012's ftp option.
- I am currently just pulling the source files one at a time.
- Since I don't have the site opened as a project in Visual Studio, the classes are not recognized.
- The site works on the development server so the classes must be defined somewhere. But in VS, they appear as undefined.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I track down a class definition in a huge directory with no apparent structure?

Comment: Search for "class X" using grep?

Comment: Use a search tool, like: http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack.  But ideally as you said, you would download the entire project.  If you need to make changes, you'll have to build the project anyway.

Comment: xDaevax, do you want to submit that as an answer? That worked perfectly since I didn't have the file name nor exact location. Thanks bud!

Comment: Why can't you ssh into the server and forego ftp entirely? "I can't seem to connect through Visual Studio 2012's ftp option..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an ideal situation, you would have a local project / solution directory so you can make changes to the project and compile them (then push a compiled / optimized version out to the site).

Failing that, you can use a tool such as Agent Ransack to search for instances of the class definition without the aid of Studio.

Here is a link to the software: http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack

Comment: Please help me improve the answer.  Could the downvoter please elaborate?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but Agent Ranshack only runs on Windows. So your solution doesn't work for the vast majority of non-legacy developers. That could be why, even though the question is tagged "legacy" and Windows is a legacy OS.

Comment: @JaneGoodall  You gave many generalizations that I would like to respectfully disagree with. Given that: *Microsoft* .NET using MS Visual Studio (which runs on Windows only) and deployed to a web server (is most likely run on a Windows server), I think a *Windows* only piece of software is applicable.  The OP uses the tag "legacy" to refer to the inherited code (which they wish to change using Visual Studio), not the OS.

Comment: @JaneGoodall that being said, neither does .NET run on Linux / Mac without additional configuration. Also "the vast majority of non-legacy developers" is in my personal experience still (too often) using windows ...

Answer (score 1):

Since you're working on an ASP.NET site, you probably need a UNIX-like environment like Cygwin for your legacy OS.

After installing Cygwin, if you know the filename that the class definition is in, you could [pipe `find` into `grep`](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1165492&s=67855b865527f7c9a14c8e041ca8f6a7&p=7317282#post7317282):

```
cd /your/project/directory
find . -name FILENAME | xargs grep "CLASS-DEFINITION"
```

Otherwise, you can list all occurrences of the class definition string in the terminal. The filenames will be next to the occurrences so you may be able to pick out the right file. This may be difficult if the class definition is referenced times:

```
cd /your/project/directory
grep -r "CLASS-DEFINITION" .
```

See also [`bro grep`](http://bropages.org/), though if you're on OS X you'll need different syntax or `gsed` from brew.

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning here.  Since ASP.NET runs on Windows platforms, why would the OP need to install a UNIX-like environment on top of his Windows OS to look for something in a remote FTP directory?  In addition, the OP specifically states they do *not* know the filename.  Also, can ASP.NET using Visual Studio be developed on OS X without a Windows virtual?

Comment: Because a developer with his experience and a UNIX-like environment wouldn't even have to ask this question.